# colors values for discord - python

Tags: python, discord

Hi everyone where i can find the value for each color for Discord embed?

`color=16711680`

Is there a sort of list where I can find all the values like 16711680?

Thanks to everyone in advance

Comment: Is the color in the question red? If so, the color is probably a 3-byte number, with the high byte representing red, the middle representing green, and the low representing blue (each on a 0-255 scale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the class methods of the [`discord.Colour`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Colour) class.  Those will generate `Colour` instances with a `value` attribute that is the number you're looking for.